# finding the count, pass and fail percentage of the multiple values from single column while aggregating another column using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

Data

[image: Data]

I want to apply groupby for column1 and want to calculate the percentage of passed and failed percentage for each 1 and as well count

### Example ouput I am looking for

[image: Result]

Using pyspark I am doing the below code but I am only getting the percentage

```
 levels = ["passed", "failed","blocked"]

 exprs = [avg((col("Column2") == level).cast("double")*100).alias(level)
          for level in levels]
 df = sparkSession.read.json(hdfsPath)
 result1 = df1.select('Column1','Column2').groupBy("Column1").agg(*exprs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to explicitly calculate the counts, and then do some string formatting to combine the percentages in the counts into a single column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, col, count, concat, lit

levels = ["passed", "failed","blocked"]

# percentage aggregations
pct_exprs = [avg((col("Column2") == level).cast("double")*100).alias('{}_pct'.format(level))
              for level in levels]
# count aggregations
count_exprs = [sum((col("Column2") == level).cast("int")).alias('{}_count'.format(level))
               for level in levels]
# combine all aggregations
exprs = pct_exprs + count_exprs

# string formatting select expressions
select_exprs = [
    concat(
        col('{}_pct'.format(level)).cast('string'),
        lit('('),
        col('{}_count'.format(level)).cast('string'),
        lit(')')
    ).alias('{}_viz'.format(level))
    for level in levels
]

df = sparkSession.read.json(hdfsPath)
result1 = (
    df1
    .select('Column1','Column2')
    .groupBy("Column1")
    .agg(*exprs)
    .select('Column1', *select_exprs)
)
```

NB: it seems like you are trying to use Spark to make a nice visualization of the results of your calculations, but I don't think Spark is well-suited for this task. If you have few enough records that you can see all of them at once, you might as well work locally in Pandas or something similar. And if you have enough records that using Spark makes sense, then you can't see all of them at once anyway so it doesn't matter too much whether they look nice.

Comment: Hi abeboparebop ,Thanks for the solution, Its worked.
I am using on top of 1 million records, I have just shown the example

Comment: When I am doing individual it is working fine for percentage and count but when i am combining the both columns are differing and throwing an exception

Comment: What kind of error? I didn't test my code -- I'm guessing it's because I didn't initially cast the numeric types as string in the final concat. I've just made an edit to fix this.

Comment: I got this error now :
raise ParseException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u'\nDataType str is not supported.(line 1, pos 0)\n\n== SQL ==\nstr\n^^^\n'

Comment: Fixed another syntax error (missing parenthesis) and the issue you mentioned with the cast to string.

Comment: only printing Failed ones without Passed

Comment: I'm not sure why that's happening, but please create a reproducible example to make it easier to help you further. (For example, in your original screenshot, I can see both uppercase and lowercase values for Passed/passed, which would be a problem for this approach.)

Comment: hey thank you, Its working fine. Because of that string conversion I have faced problem